# OGX.JS capture values from route

Tags: javascript, ogx.js

I'm using `OGX.JS`. I'm trying to add a dynamic route to a view but I can't seem to capture the values. Here is my route.

```
  "mystage/invoices/([a-z0-9]{24})/([a-z0-9]{24}):OML": "invoices"
```

In my view `invoices` I have

```
   this.construct = function(__data, __route_data){        
        console.log('ROUTE', __route_data);
   };
```

But __route_data is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. You have to declare the property of the object in your route such as

```
  "mystage/invoices/propertyA:([a-z0-9]{24})/propertyB:([a-z0-9]{24}):OML": "invoices"
```

Then it should be available in `__route_data` as

```
 __route_data.propertyA
 __route_data.propertyB
```